# Overriding coroutines not working as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
protected virtual IEnumerator Lerp()
    {
        Debug.Log("BaseMethod");

        while (true)
        {
            speed = startSpeed;
            currentColor = SpriteRend.color;
            float r = Random.Range(0f, 1f),
                g = Random.Range(0f, 1f),
                b = Random.Range(0f, 1f),
                a = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
            nextColor = new Color(r, g, b, a);

            while (nextColor != (currentColor = Color.Lerp(currentColor, nextColor, speed * Time.deltaTime)))
            {

                if (AnyRgbValueReached())
                {
                    speed += 2f;
                }

                SpriteRend.color = currentColor;
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }



protected override IEnumerator Lerp()
    {
        if (IsFirst)
        {
            while (!Game.GameInstance.GameOver)
            {
                if (Recording)
                {
                    Debug.Log("SubMethod");
                    yield return base.Lerp();                                                
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return null;

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

            while (!Game.GameInstance.GameOver)
            {
                SpriteRend.color = firstTop.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: these 2 methods aren't in 1 class, they are in 2 separate classes.

The problem is that the Debug.Log("BaseMethod"); doesn't get printed while the Debug.Log("SubMethod"); is being printed every single frame. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please copy (the relevant portions of) your code into your question, unless you can *guarantee* that the linked pages will be available at least for as long as this question will be accessible online. Otherwise, your question may become useless for future visitors if at some point in the future, your links go dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 protected override IEnumerator Lerp()
 {
     if (IsFirst)
     {
         while (!Game.GameInstance.GameOver)
         {
             if (Recording)
             {
                 Debug.Log("SubMethod");
                 yield return StartCoroutin(base.Lerp());    // See here                                             
             }
             else
             {
                 yield return null;

             }
         }
     }
    // Rest of code
 }
```

This is a coroutine so it should be called like one.

Comment: Just a note that if you do it this way the current coroutine won't continue until the new one has finished. So you can try as well
 ' IEnumerator baseLerp = base.Lerp();
 while (baseLerp.MoveNext()) {
     yield return null;
 }'

Hope it helps! :) Tell me if there is something that you don't understand.

Comment: This code has the nasty side effect of starting a new coroutine rather than continuing inside the callstack of the calling one.

If this idiom were used in a public function returning IEnumerator then it could cause a coroutine to be spawned whose execution was managed by an entirely different object than the original object on which StartCoroutine() was called which could cause all sorts of nasty stuff including crashes which happen many frames later thatn the original function call which lead to them and with a different object.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to accomplish this same thing would (IMO) be to do what I've outlined below.

This removes the **very** nasty side effect of kicking off a separate coroutine - and potentially on a different Monobehaviour than the original one for which StartCoroutine() was called.

It also has the advantage that using the same approach you could nest additional IEnumerators (more or less) indefinitely if you needed to.

```
public class BaseClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    // you'd normally start this using StartCoroutine( ... )
    public IEnumerator Lerp( /*params*/ )
    {
        // this is (approx.) how monobehaviour internally manages the coroutines you start with StartCoroutine()
        IEnumerator cInternalCoroutine = VInternalCoroutine( /*params*/ );

        // each call to MoveNext() progresses the IEnumerator to the next yield 
        // or end of the function if cInternalCoroutine.MoveNext() reaches the 
        // end of the function, or it returns "yield break" MoveNext() returns false 
        // & the loop ends
        while( cInternalCoroutine.MoveNext() )
        {
            yield return cInternalCoroutine.Current;
        }
    }

    protected virtual IEnumerator VInternalCoroutine( /*params*/ )
    {
        // write this just like a regular coroutine
        Debug.LogFormat( "{0}.{1}", 
                            GetType().Name, 
                            System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name );
        yield return null;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override IEnumerator VInternalCoroutine()
    {
        // write this just like a regular coroutine
        Debug.LogFormat( "{0}.{1}", 
                            GetType().Name, 
                            System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name );
        yield return null;
    }
}
```